# Xcode project not showing list of simulators

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6.1

I open my project in Xcode 6.1. When I try to run the project, the button is grayed out. When I try to go to `Product > Clean`, the option is grayed out. When I look at the list of simulators, all I get is `My Mac` instead of the usually `iOS Device`. How do I get my simulators to come back?

Comment: Check in Menu Xode->Preferences->Download, if there are all possible simulators. Check your target, is it correct.

Comment: I tried a few answers, but non worked. Then I restarted my Mac and everything was back to normal. Not sure if all I needed was a restart or if the changes **+** the restart was necessary

Comment: Sometimes only the restart of XCode/Mac will do

Comment: New one in 2023, when none of these answers works (no, I'm not adding this as a 0-score answer at the bottom of Page 3): top menu "Product" > Destination > Destination Architectures > "Show Both"   Hope this helps somebody (where the plethora of answers from 2018 might not).

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Click on the project name (Right to the Run button). Three options will appear.

1. Edit scheme
2. New scheme
3. Manage scheme

You can click on "New scheme" and then click on "OK" in popup window.

You will have simulators list back.

Comment: This worked for me. But I run into same problem when I try to change iPhone in simulator, and then this same scheme doesn't work any longer even if I go back to the previous simulator. I have to do New Scheme once again. I am using Xcode 12.2. There is still some bug somewhere in Xcode.

Comment: Also Worked for me with Xcode 14.1 !

Answer (score 234):

Make sure that the project you are trying to run has `deployment target` equal to or less then the SDK version of your Xcode. In my case I tried to run a project which was built using `iOS8.4` but I have Xcode6.1 with SDK version 8.1

I changed the deployment target to 8.1 and it start showing me simulators.

P.S before doing this, make sure that your code and external libraries are compatible with your new deployment target, else you have to update your Xcode.

Comment: This happened when my xCode version updated, and new simulators loaded, but the simulator service was still running.  This will correct it: sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService

Comment: In my case, my system version does not support some iOS versions. To check this just run this command (xcrun simctl list runtimes) in terminal. When I run this I got these results: iOS 9.3 (9.3 - 13E233) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-9-3 (unavailable, The iOS 9.3 simulator runtime is not supported on hosts after macOS 10.14.99.)
iOS 10.0 (10.0 - 14A345) - (unavailable, The iOS 10.0 simulator runtime is not supported on hosts after macOS 10.14.99.)
iOS 10.3 (10.3.1 - 14E8301) - (unavailable, The iOS 10.3 simulator runtime is not supported on hosts after macOS 10.15.99.)

Comment: downgrading deployment targets from iOS 12 to 10 in Podfile and Xcode worked for me.

Answer (score 129):

Try This, It worked like a charm! for me,

**Follow below step**

1) Clean **Derived Data** as show below,

```
 rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/

OR

 Xcode---> Preferences--->Location--->Derived Data
```

[image: Derived Data]

2) **In Deployment Info change** **Deployment Target**

It's **equal** to or **less** then the **SDK** version of **Xcode**

[image]

3) **Quit** **Xcode**

[image]

4) Reopen **Xcode** you will see list of **simulators**

[image]

Hope this answer will help for someone.

Comment: Why this happening, is there any reason they don't want to show the simulator list?

Answer (score 113):

I could not find any solution that would fix my issue. All simulators were there for all projects but the one that I needed them.

Solution:

Build Settings -> Architectures -> Supported Platforms:

> changed from **iphoneos** to **iOS**

Comment: Also on Unity. It made the simulators show up but it still wouldn't build. The solution was to go to the Unity Editor and set `Unity -> Build settings -> Player Settings -> Other Settings -> Target SDK = Simulator SDK`

Comment: This alone solved it for me

Comment: Holy heck, man. Yes. Changing to Simulator SDK is the ONLY thing that works if you're using Unity.  Also, works easily after that. Just build to a different output folder.

Answer (score 82):

Also check the `iOS Deployment Target` under build settings.

Somehow the Deployment Target gets set to most latest SDK that won't have available simulators.

Select the available SDK version and simulator list should be back available again. Cheers!

[image]

Answer (score 27):

Cmd below solved my problem:

```
$ sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

---

In my case, I upgraded to Xcode 8 and downloaded another version 7.3.1 later (renamed it to "Xcode 7.3.1"), then cannot get the simulator list in Xcode 8.

Comment: Tried this and "edit scheme" thing mentioned earlier, neither worked out. So I was curious and tried to run the simulator itself. Got this error: Unable to determine simulator device to boot. I followed the suggestion by thegreenpizza at this post and it worked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011986/unable-to-determine-simulator-device-to-boot-xcode-6

Answer (score 25):

In my case i'd accidentally deleted ios devices in system Finder -> Library->Devices->Core simulator

So, the simulators are not listed in the Xcode project except ios device.

I solved this by adding ios simuulators from Xcode->Window->Devices->Add simulators

[image]

Hope it'll help someone.

Answer (score 16):

For those coming from Unity, even if you manage to make them show up (by changing `Build Settings > Supported Platforms` to `iOS` it would not run in the simulator.

Instead, you need to select this Simulator SDK :

[image]

And make sure something other than Metal exist.

[image]

Then the simulator device list will be there from start.

Comment: Just a note that the "Target SDK" setting listed above is under `Build Settings` -> `Player Settings` -> `iOS (little iphone icon on the menu)` -> `Other Settings` -> `Target SDK` in the Unity UI

Comment: Kinda defeats the point of a simulator if you have to select a target device. Whilst this does seem to be a way, it didn't work for me because none of the plugin libraries i'm using were compiled for Simulator use. So ultimately pointless waist of time. Also, note that this will trigger an asset reimport FYI.

Answer (score 11):

Solution:
Build Settings -> Architectures -> Supported Platforms:
changed from iphoneos to iOS

Confirmed works in Xcode Version 9.0 (9A235)

Answer (score 10):

Deployment Target version change to a lower one helped for me:

Window -> Devices and Simulators -> Simulators. Check what are the latest versions of existing simulators.

[image: simulators]

Then go to your project's Target. Under Deployment Info, change Target to the version you saw the latest within your simulators. Mine was set to iOS 13.6 when the simulator was iOS 13.5 only.

[image: deployment-target]

Answer (score 8):

check in your project's build settings , make certain you select Latest iOS (iOS 8.1).

Answer (score 8):

If you renamed Xcode.app since first launch, the iOS Simulator becomes unavailable.  This is mentioned in the [Xcode 6.1 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/xc6_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH4-DontLinkElementID_24):

> Renaming Xcode.app after running any of the Xcode tools in that bundle
>   may cause iOS Simulator to be no longer be available. Either rename
>   Xcode.app back to what it was when first launched or restart your Mac.
>   (16646772)

Answer (score 8):

Go to Window then Devices and press the plus button at the bottom left to add a device and select the simulator which are required.This worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes the simulator you have might not be the simulator specified in **Build Settings**.
Make sure that simulator package is downloaded for your **IOS Deployment Target**

Answer (score 6):

**If Your problem is due to multiple (versions of) xcode**

Then follow following steps

**1. Cleaning Derived Data**
Go to Xcode preferences -> Select location tab -> select little gray arrow on /Users/apple/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData. You will be redirect to folder From there select Derived Data folder and Delete.
[image]

**2. Completely Quite The Xcode and reopen**

This will solve your problem.
Happy coding :)

Answer (score 5):

Same Problem happened with me.. When I updated from Xcode 8 Beta 3 to Xcode 8 Beta 4, But I resolved it by this way..

1. Go to **Window -> Devices**

you can see all Devices and Simulators here

2. Just **right click** on any device or simulator
3. Tick on **Show in Destination Menu** (Even it is already checked, then click it twice, It may be refresh things)

If above does not work.. as if you do not see any simulators, then..

1. Change(degrade) the minimum deployment target of app to 8.3(not necessary)
2. restart xcode

It worked for me.. Hope will be helpful for someone later..

Answer (score 5):

Quite Xcode and Open it again, it will show. For me it's worked.

Answer (score 5):

Just check your **Deployment Target** where **XCode** support it or not.

Answer (score 5):

In my case the problem was in **Architectures** parameter.
It was set to **arm64**
I just changed the value to **Standard Architectures (arm64, armv7) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)**
Then `pod install`
[image]

Comment: This one did the trick for me, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like Xcode hides that menu when the window is a certain size. You have to make your window quite large before it comes back.

Answer (score 4):

**Small but a effective solution.**
In my case i updated to my xcode to 9.2 version and simulators disappeared.

I found this solution and it worked for me and for others also.

**

> Just quit your xcode and restart again. You will have simulators.

**

Answer (score 4):

If you updated Xcode to 12.1. Completely quit Xcode and it will install components.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with xCode 14.0.1. Replacing the target architecture from "arm64" to "$(ARCHS_STANDARD)" brought back the list of simulators.

Answer (score 3):

I still had my `iOS Device`, but all my simulators were gone.

I tried every suggested solution I could find on stackoverflow.

Eventually, I **deleted the Xcode app and downloaded it again** from the App Store. After installation, the simulators were back.

Answer (score 3):

I just needed a good, old fashioned restart the computer. When uninstalling and reinstalling XCode didn't do the job, I restarted out of pure frustration....lo and behold! After a restart, everything was as it should be.

Comment: I was really sweating it as I read thru these answers (while downloading Xcode in the background). I decided to give your answer a shot as it was low risk and I have a habit of NOT restarting for long periods. Sadly, solutions for the Mac are becoming more similar to THE solution for Windows: reboot. Happily though, it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you just updated Xcode, you may need to restart your computer before simulators become available again.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into another situation where this can occur. I work with a team we use Xcode server for continuous integration. The server wasn't seeing any simulators, but only for one project. I eventually determined that this was due to the fact that the version of Xcode on our server was one release earlier, and the Xcode project was set to build to the newest version available. Simply updating Xcode solved the issue for us.

Answer (score 2):

I had this happen to me after an update to a new Xcode. Running

```
xcode-select --install
```

fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

Just go to Xcode -> Window -> Devices

Click + at the bottom left

Add your new Simulator

Answer (score 2):

After upgrading to Xcode 10.3, the list of simulators was empty.  I rebooted and it was resolved.

This doesn't necessarily answer the OP's specific question, but this was the first place I ended up in researching my Xcode 10.3 upgrade issue.

Comment: I just upgraded to 10.3 and faced the same issue. Alternatively, you can run the command shown in the answer provided by @riik https://stackoverflow.com/a/56832489

Answer (score 2):

Lower the Deployment Target version. For example you have set the target as iOS 13.4 but your Xcode version is lower and there is no iOS 13.4 installed simulator.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, generated from an imported project, the project had 10.3 as deployment target and I only had 10.0 installed, changing the deployment target to 10.0 solved my issues.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone struggling with this, I tried the mentioned options without success. Turns out all I needed to do was just quit and relaunch Xcode. Simple things can be annoying sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had created a static library target for tvOS in Xcode 8.3.3, and the tvOS simulator was not showing up in the list. Eventually found out that `TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY` in the Build Settings was set to `1,2` instead of `3`. Leaving this here incase anyone else encounters the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I simply Renamed my Xcode file in Application folder to something else and renamed it back to Xcode.

Worked

Answer (score 1):

Install iOS Simulator if you're missing one.

[image: Click here to see how.]

Answer (score 1):

Nothing worked for me, except

```
gem install snapshot

fastlane snapshot reset_simulators
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I thought I created a new project using the iOS Framework template, but I inadvertently selected the macOS Framework template instead. This was preventing me from building the project for iPhone simulators. Deleting the project and recreating it, this time selecting the iOS Framework template, fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Product->Destination->Destination Architecture->Show Both**

After that, you see all simulators

[image]

Comment: The question is about Xcode 6.1. Apple Silicon didn't exist at that time.

Comment: And what so? You think that currently we haven't problem with "hidden" simulators? And one more, in case what i post, in start was hidden not only rosetta simulators, for example i can't see any simulators with 14.x IOS

Answer (score 0):

Check if in the app store under xcode it says GET instead of installed, delete your current version and get the new one

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem when I update my xcode to 8.2beta (with the app name xcode-beta.app), I found the answer above by Jeremy Huddleston Sequoia and tried to rename xcode-beta.app to xcode.app, it worked. I guess the name should be xcode.app to use the simulators, even if you didn't changed the name by yourself when you download the beta one.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing helped me so I downloaded the simulators for my deployment Target.

- Beside play button and target name where simulator is chosen,
- Click the simulator to see the simulator list window.
- Click on the last button is "Download Simulators"
- Download the simulators for your deployment Target

  You can check Deployment target :
- Below play button 1st tab i.e. Project navigator, Click it and click on Project name
- Select your target > General tab > Deployment Info > Deployment target.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

After trying a lot of suggestions, the below command solved the issue for me.

Try to restart the simulator service:

```
sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService
```

Answer (score -1):

**Go Preferences > Locations**
[image]

**Delete Derived Data Folder**

[image]

Open Terminal at your project folder > run `pod install`

Problem will be solved !