# Xcode archive linker error dlib

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, dlib

I have this error when archiving project in Xcode.

```
ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because '/project/Pods/dlib/build/libdlib.dylib' was built without full bitcode. All frameworks and dylibs for bitcode must be generated from Xcode Archive or Install build for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Don't know what to do :( Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try clearing derived data ?

Comment: @dip How can I do it?

Comment: in build settings set `Enable Bitcode` to ***No***

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44427019/3236890 to clear derived data!

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik but I need this parameter to setting YES, because I want to upload project to App Store

Comment: @EvgeniyaTveritinova - Bitcode is used for multiple domain deployment purpose, if your app is only used in iOS, then set as ***NO*** does not create the problem

Comment: Check https://medium.com/@heitorburger/static-libraries-frameworks-and-bitcode-6d8f784478a9

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find answer here [xcode 7.1 swift framework app builds but not archiving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33580528/xcode-7-1-swift-framework-app-builds-but-not-archiving/33581287)