# Xcode simulator list missing (9.4.1) after updating to Mojave

Tags: xcode, macos-mojave

Trying to run some basic code for a homework assignment but the simulator device list is missing entirely after updating to OS Mojave. Xcode is still version 9.4.1 (version required by professor).

When I connect my iPhone 8 (running iOS 12), it displays this error which is pretty straightforward: [image: device not supported]

So I decided to run it on the simulator. However, the options are missing from the dropdown. No idea why this is happening: [image: missing simulator list]

Anyone have a solution for this? I've already tried manually adding a device, but that just duplicates the device in the list (e.g. iPhone 8):
[image: add simulator]

Comment: this answer might be help you  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26690730/xcode-project-not-showing-list-of-simulators

Comment: Resolved. This was happening because the file was originally created in Xcode 10 (I wasn't aware that it had auto-updated), then reopened in Xcode 9.4.1 after I reverted back. I recreated the project from scratch in 9.4.1 and the list is appearing.