# xcode8 list of simulators not showing

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode8, xcode8-beta4

I have been only recently working with Xcode 8 beta 4 but it has been working fine up until now. The list of simulators is not showing for any of my projects. I already tried Creating a new Scheme and it did not work. How do I fix this?

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31551480/xcode-7-ios-simulators-missing-and-not-installable

Comment: that did not help me unfortunately. I checked and it says I have the right simulators, xcode just does not give me the option to run on them

Comment: In my case, my system version does not support some iOS versions. To check this just run this command (xcrun simctl list runtimes) in terminal. When I run this I got these results: iOS 9.3 (9.3 - 13E233) - com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-9-3 (unavailable, The iOS 9.3 simulator runtime is not supported on hosts after macOS 10.14.99.) iOS 10.0 (10.0 - 14A345) - (unavailable, The iOS 10.0 simulator runtime is not supported on hosts after macOS 10.14.99.) iOS 10.3 (10.3.1 - 14E8301) - (unavailable, The iOS 10.3 simulator runtime is not supported on hosts after macOS 10.15.99.)

Answer (score 138, accepted):

Deleting derived data and restarting Xcode worked in my case.

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
```

Comment: Tried this approach but it did not work. So I was curious and tried to run the simulator itself. Got this error: Unable to determine simulator device to boot. I followed the suggestion by thegreenpizza at this post and it worked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011986/unable-to-determine-simulator-device-to-boot-xcode-6

Comment: a year past, similar problem - only Xode 9 instead of 8 (beta 6). And unfortunately, it didn't work.

Comment: Didn't work for me, although it did make the list of recent files start showing when you go to File -> Open Recent.

Answer (score 41):

Ensure your `Deployment Target` version in `Build Settings` is also set to the desired version (and that you have that version of the respective simulator installed). In the below example, if that were set to 10.3 and I didn't have an iOS 10.3 simulator installed, I wouldn't be able to see any simulators. But because it's set to 10.1, and I have 10.1 simulators installed, I can see them.
[image]

Comment: thanks for this, i had started a project targeting IOS 11 but did not have any simulators supporting the OS - setting target to 10.3 fixed the issue and supported simulators began appearing again

Comment: @DanLoewenherz glad to hear it was helpful. :)

Comment: Should be higher up. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: This worked for me—default `iOS Deployment Target` value was set to `11.0` for a new iOS 11 project. Once iOS `10.x` was selected I was able to see my iOS 10.x simulators.

Comment: You saved my day :)

Answer (score 22):

If this issue is project - specific, you opened a project which has "Supported platforms" build setting set to iphone or such. Most likely this is due to simulator not having the required capabilities or an embedded library not compiled to run on simulator.

Change this setting to "iOS" to see the simulators available for running.

[image]

Comment: **That's it !!** Thanks.

Comment: this is it. this is the one.

Answer (score 9):

Set proper deployment target. And also the simulators with greater/same deployment target versions needs to be downloaded.

Answer (score 8):

TL;DR `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

A year past OP, after installing Xcode 9 beta 6 the 10.3 simulators disappeared from xcode 8. `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*` **didn't work this time**.

Runnin `xcode-select --print-path` printed `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`.

Just to make sure, tried `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`, which worked after xcode restart.

Comment: This worked for me.. when I tried to open Xcode 9 beta, Xcode-select default path got changed. Switched back to Xcode 8 and working fine

Comment: this worked for me, i tried many methods like download new simulator quit xcode , re run xcode again, nothing worked but switch command worked for me, thanks @user1244109

Answer (score 5):

Try this , It's working perfect for me ,

Follow Below steps ,

1) Clean **Derived Data**

```
 rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
```

OR

```
 Xcode---> Preferences--->Location--->Derived Data
```

2) In Deployment Info change **Deployment Target**

It's **equal** to or **less** then the **SDK** version of **Xcode**

3) Quit **Xcode**

4) Reopen **Xcode** you will see list of **simulators**

For more details refer this [Detail Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40838769/4527240)

Hope this is help for some one.

Answer (score 5):

Please check your deployment target, Deployment target is greater than your iOS version this problem occurs.

Comment: This was my issue. I was hopping between XCode and an XCode Beta.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had to manually add all the emulators again after upgrading to Xcode 8

Click on Product -> Destination -> Add Additional Simulators --> Add Simulator.

Comment: Once here, you have to click the `+` button and choose the iOS version and iPhone type you want. You will have to download the simulators first.

Answer (score 2):

Faced a similar issue with Xcode 8.3.2 (on Sierra) where installed devices were not showing up. Unfortunately restarting Xcode did not work for me but rebooting the machine did. Also answered on [Apple developer forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/48584)

Comment: None of the other answers worked for me. Sort of to my surprise, rebooting worked and all of the Simulators are now back. Definitely +1

Answer (score 2):

*Step 1:*

**Product -> Destination -> Download Simulators**... Download the simulator(s) you need.

*Step 2:*

After you downloaded the new simulators, they don't automatically add in the list of simulators.

**Product -> Destination -> Add Additional Simulators**... Click the + button in the lower left hand corner, then Add Simulator. Give a name, device type, and the iOS version you downloaded.

*Step 3:*

Set deployment target. If you have downloaded simulators of lower versions, set the deployment target to the same.

Now, it should show up in your list of simulator devices!

Answer (score 1):

No other solutions worked for me.
I tried downloading new Simulator and restarted xCode, all simulators showing up now.

Answer (score 1):

I tried deleting all of my DerivedData but that didn't help. For some reason none of the devices were appearing, although all the simulators were in the list when I clicked "Add Simulators".
I took a shot and tried Product -> Build For -> Running and compiled the app. Once it succeeded, all my devices reappeared.

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

I renamed by Xcode.app to  Xcode_old.app and suddenly all my simulators gone also not able to add new simulators. Then i created new folder with name Xcode (or whatever you want) then paste the xcode 8.3 version in that.

Answer (score 1):

Two steps

**Step 1:**

Product -> Destination -> Download Simulators...
Download the simulator(s) you need

If the simulators show up in list next to schemes, you're all set! Otherwise, continue to...

**Step 2:**

Sometimes when you download the new simulator types, they don't automatically show in the list of possible simulators.

Product -> Destination -> Add Additional Simulators...
Click the `+` button in the lower left hand corner, then `Add Simulator`
Give it a name, device type, and the iOS version you just downloaded.

Now it should show up in your list of simulator devices!

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps to fix this issue.

Step 1: Quit all the XCodes and respective simulators.

Step 2: Open Xcode 8 and go to Xcode Menu -> Open Developer tool -> Simulator.

Step 3: Quit the Xcode 8 and reopen.

Answer (score 0):

You can Go on menu bar: Go to folder enter below path 
 ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/
Select Device and delete all device list and reopen x-code project its working fine