# XCode 8.3 beta can't find simulator runtime

Tags: xcode8

I am using XCode 8.1 without problem (both device and simulator). One of my test devices is on 10.3 beta 3, so I need to run XCode 8.3 beta. It fails with the following error:

> /Users/phil/dev/kokomot/Kokomot/Kokomot.xcdatamodeld/Kokomot.xcdatamodel:
>   **Cannot find cdtool** at
>   '/var/folders/9x/wrdwltwx6jg6f7tzfrjq6d5c0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/4337E592-3A26-47A2-BFA2-9A5B067EC6CB/d/Xcode-8.3-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Agents/cdtool':
>   **Cannot find a simulator runtime** for platform
>   >.

Note that the "cdtool" error is misleading; the cdtool is there, but presumably won't run because of the simulator runtime error.

UPDATE: Got this working in XCode 8.1 by symlinking to the 10.3 folder in the XCode beta: https://gist.github.com/steipete/d9b44d8e9f341e81414e86d7ff8fb62d

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44471971/xcode-9-bug-cannot-find-cdtool

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a problem directly related to a malformed installation. I've been there after downloading and installing `XCode` from browser.

I have solved it by deleting `XCode` and installing directly from App Store application on Mac.

Comment: check this link I think this is the right solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38831954/xcode8-list-of-simulators-not-showing

Comment: reinstall help me.