# iOS: xcode 9.3 no simulator found for iOS 11.3 after update

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode9.3, ios11.3

Recently i have updated my Mac OS version to  High Sierra(10.13.4).Then I updated the `XCODE` version to `Version 9.3`. After successful installation i am trying to run my project on it i found there is no simulator for this version of `xcode 10.13.4`.
Then i tried to download simulator from `xcode` preferences it only shows simulator list with `11.2` as latest simulator.Also in

> Window --> Devices and Simulator

nothing found.
Is there any other link from where i can download the simulator for `iOS 11.3`?

[image]

[image]

Comment: try to change your project deployment target and restart xcode

Comment: You’re in the wrong window. Look in Devices and Simulators.

Comment: @matt i tried there too but nothing happen

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38831954/xcode8-list-of-simulators-not-showing

Comment: You tried what?

Comment: Look in Devices and Simulators and trying to add new simulator by tapping on create button nothing happened

Comment: Though @matt has marked it duplicate, I would still like to know if the solution(s) in the link fixed this issue.

Comment: @AbhinandanPratap : Please do inform us if your issue got fixed or not by following the link.

Comment: @Nitish not fixed still searching some possible solution of it

Comment: @AbhinandanPratap : Check the other question linked as duplicate.

Comment: @Nitish i removed the derived data and restart xcode it works for me thanks for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are right, `ios 11.3` simulator is not listed in component list but it is by default available with Xcode 9.3. And there is no other reference to download it manually.

Remove all reference of previous Xcode and install Xcode 9.3 source. From Xcode - target device list, it will automatically launch simulator with iOS 11.3.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: i tried this but it shows empty list and when i select device type and click on create nothing happen

Comment: i removed the derived data and restart xcode it works for me thanks for help