# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 / i386

Tags: ios, rust, cross-compiling

I've a native lib that is communication with sqlite3, it works fine within Android, so, I compiled it for iOS, compilation process completed smoothly, but at the time of exciting, i.e. once building the iOS app in Xcode, I got the below error:

> symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "_sqlite3_column_int64", referenced from:
>         rusqlite::statement::Statement::value_ref::h1ef4d7e4ee859386 in libgreetings.a(rusqlite-39d80e8cd3d6a115.rusqlite.99wt63ts-cgu.3.rcgu.o)
>     "_sqlite3_column_blob", referenced from:
>         rusqlite::statement::Statement::value_ref::h1ef4d7e4ee859386 in libgreetings.a(rusqlite-39d80e8cd3d6a115.rusqlite.99wt63ts-cgu.3.rcgu.o)
>     "_sqlite3_bind_int64", referenced from:
>         rusqlite::statement::Statement::bind_parameter::hc14d4185381afdbf in 
>      ...
>      ...
>      ...

Even when I changed the `iOS Development target` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43709211/2441637) and installed simulator iOS 10, and changed the `Architectures` to `$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)` instead of `$(ARCHS_STANDARD)` as shown [here](https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/buildsettings.html#archs_standard_32_64_bit) I got the same error with:

> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386

Note: The lib is built using rust and [rusqlite](https://github.com/jgallagher/rusqlite) crate, the lib was called smoothly and executed very well before adding the sqlite part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should link against sqlite3 library first before you compile the app.
follow the step:

1. go to the target's "Build Phases" -> "Link Binary With Libraries" section.
2. click add "+".
3. search sqlite.
4. select "libsqlite3.tbd", "tbd" is new extension of dylib file in iOS.
5. click "Add"
   now your app successfully linked to sqlite lib, the error should have gone.